# Issue with CTE in stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I have a stored procedure like this.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get_leave_deduction;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_leave_deduction(
    IN emp_ID VARCHAR(255),
    IN month_ INT,
    IN year_ YEAR
)

BEGIN
DECLARE last_date DATE;
SET last_date = LAST_DAY(DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', year_, month_, 1)));

WITH tmp_table AS (

    SELECT *
    CASE
        WHEN tl.end_date > last_date THEN datediff(last_date, tl.start_date)
        ELSE datediff(tl.end_date, tl.start_date)
    END AS 'num_days'
    FROM takes_leave AS tl
    WHERE tl.emp_ID = emp_ID and month(tl.start_date)<=month_ and year(tl.start_date)=year_;
    )
    
    SELECT * FROM tmp_table;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL get_leave_deduction("8", 11, 2023)
```

I get the following error in MYSQL Workbench when I try to run it: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE
WHEN tl.end_date > last_date THEN datediff(last_date, tl.start_date)

Workbench doesnt show this error when I comment the WHERE and CASE statement in the tmp_table CTE. So I'm guessing the error has something to do with not able to use input parameters inside CTE.
I want to use the contents of this CTE inside the stored procedure to create another query.

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH tmp_table AS (

SELECT *
        ^^ you need a comma between items in the select-list
CASE
    WHEN tl.end_date > last_date THEN datediff(last_date, tl.start_date)
    ELSE datediff(tl.end_date, tl.start_date)
END AS 'num_days'
FROM takes_leave AS tl
WHERE tl.emp_ID = emp_ID 
    and month(tl.start_date)<=month_ 
    and year(tl.start_date)=year_;
                                 ^^ do not use a semicolon 
                                    inside subquery or CTE
)

SELECT * FROM tmp_table;
```

Also don't name your procedure arguments the same as column names in your table. When you use the procedure variables in a query, it becomes ambiguous if you mean the variable or the column. In this case, `emp_ID` is the same name. Using qualified identifiers may help resolve the ambiguity, but your code will be more clear and easier to debug if you make sure the variable name is different from the column name.

Don't rely on syntax hints from MySQL Workbench. If you are in doubt about syntax, learn to read reference documentation.